# Image loading showing error: EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE

Tags: dart, flutter

I am loading image from URL for my circle avatar and it is showing me following error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:codec.cc(97)] Failed decoding image. Data is either invalid, or it is encoded using an unsupported format.
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
flutter: Exception: operation failed
```

Here is my code for this:

```
CircleAvatar(
 backgroundColor: blueColor,
 radius: 45,
 child: new Text( strFName.substring(0, 1) + strLName.substring(0, 1) style: styleCircleName,),
 backgroundImage: NetworkImage(strImageURL),
)
```

Comment: what's the image format? can you post the image URL?

Answer (score 0):

The error `Failed decoding image. Data is either invalid, or it is encoded using an unsupported format.` is usually caused by trying to display an invalid image. An image could possibly be invalid if it's in an incorrect format i.e. trying to display an "incomplete" base64 image, path to the image file/asset being incorrect.

The image formats supported by Flutter are listed [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html). Some of them are JPEG, PNG, GIF, Animated GIF, WebP, Animated WebP, BMP, and WBMP.